# Is there a japanese kana font on the iphone by default?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unicode, internationalization, uilabel

I was wondering if there is a built-in font for Japanese kana in the iPhone OS?

I was wanting to display kana characters and figured it would be easier to generate them in a UILabel as text versus creating a .PNG and display them in a UIImageView.  I would want this to be available to non-Japanese iPhones/iPods.  I'm not 100% aware if there are differences in the localizations of them as I could not find any of this info in the Dev. Center.  Thank you for our time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a font which contains Hiragana, Katakana and Kanji. I'm not sure if there's a way to specify the style of the font though.

You can type Japanese straight into an 'NSString' and set the label text, it will show up no problem.

**Edit: ** I found this list of fonts on the iPhone, which lists "Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN W3", a Japanese font. You can find it on the Mac too, it's the standard Japanese font. There's also a bold version. There doesn't seem to be a rounded version, just gothic.

http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2008/10/05/snippet-available-uifonts/

Comment: HA!  Yes!  It works!  Thank you very much.  This has saved me a TON of time with doing future Photoshop work and will make my code much cleaner than dealing with .PNGs of Kana.